# csv file generate and save it in specific folder using php any one can help me

Tags: php

`enter code here`

> ****Here generate CSV file and its download directly when submit form but i want save it in specific folder plz any one can help me ...****

```
 <?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))                    
{
//collect form data
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$mobileno = $_POST['mobileno'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if(!isset($error)){

  $Content = "Name,Address,Mobile,Email \n";

    //set the data of the CSV
    $Content .= "$name,$address,$mobileno,$email\n";

    //set the file name and create CSV file
    $FileName = $name."-".date("d-m-y-h:i:s").".csv";
    header('Content-Type: application/csv'); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $FileName . '"'); 
    echo $Content;
    exit();
  }
 }

 //if their are errors display them
if(isset($error)){
foreach($error as $error){
    echo '<p style="color:#ff0000">$error</p>';
   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: You mean save it into a specific folder on the user's machine when they've donwnloaded it? You can't do that...the user's machine is not under the control of your website. Your website has no way of knowing whether the download even gets accepted by the receiving machine, it cannot know what folders are available or what the user has permission to, etc etc. Your code does not even know what kind of device is making the request to it. Imagine the horrendous security consequences if what you are proposing was possible...

Comment: So in conclusion no you can't do it. You can just offer the file to the user as you are doing now. It's up to them what they do with it.

Comment: I want save file in our website folder only

Comment: Create CSV file using PHP and save it into directory that it

Comment: or data save it in excel file in our website folder

Comment: Ok well you can already easily google how to save a variable to a file using PHP, that's not a secret piece of information. What have you researched? What have you tried? The solution is simple but I'm going to let you figure it out for yourself first, because it's a good lesson to learn as a programmer that most things you need to know, especially when you're relatively new, are already available online if you take a moment to search.

Comment: i tried but i'm not geting whatever i want plz help any one here submit data save it in excel sheet

Comment: So you didn't find out that file_put_contents can be used to write data to a file in PHP?? What exactly did you type into google? Just search "php save data to file" and you get 100s of useful results. Sometimes I despair that people wish to be programmers or other information industry professionals, and yet seemingly do not know how to use a search engine effectively.

Comment: BTW asn aside, you do understand that a CSV file is _not_ an Excel sheet, yes?? Excel can open CSV files, sure, but a CSV file is actually just a plain text file with certain formatting rules. An Excel-specific XLSX file is something entirely different.